# UrbanAirship NPE

Tags: android, urbanairship.com

I am getting the following NPE while installing my app itself. Please help.

```
07-22 16:27:06.380: E/UA AP(6071): Unable to takeOff automatically
07-22 16:27:06.385: D/AndroidRuntime(6071): Shutting down VM
07-22 16:27:06.385: W/dalvikvm(6071): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x415db2a0)
07-22 16:27:06.385: E/AndroidRuntime(6071): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-22 16:27:06.385: E/AndroidRuntime(6071): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.urbanairship.push.GCMPushReceiver: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-22 16:27:06.385: E/AndroidRuntime(6071): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2277)
07-22 16:27:06.385: E/AndroidRuntime(6071): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:140)
07-22 16:27:06.385: E/AndroidRuntime(6071): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
07-22 16:27:06.385: E/AndroidRuntime(6071): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-22 16:27:06.385: E/AndroidRuntime(6071): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-22 16:27:06.385: E/AndroidRuntime(6071): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
07-22 16:27:06.385: E/AndroidRuntime(6071): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-22 16:27:06.385: E/AndroidRuntime(6071): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-22 16:27:06.385: E/AndroidRuntime(6071): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
07-22 16:27:06.385: E/AndroidRuntime(6071): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
07-22 16:27:06.385: E/AndroidRuntime(6071): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-22 16:27:06.385: E/AndroidRuntime(6071): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-22 16:27:06.385: E/AndroidRuntime(6071): at com.urbanairship.UAirship.getPackageName(Unknown Source)
07-22 16:27:06.385: E/AndroidRuntime(6071): at com.urbanairship.push.GCMPushReceiver.onReceive(Unknown Source)
07-22 16:27:06.385: E/AndroidRuntime(6071): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2270)
07-22 16:27:06.385: E/AndroidRuntime(6071): ... 10 more
```

Even though I get this excepting I am able to start the app. On running :

```
url -X POST -u "<app id>:<mastersecret>" -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"android": {"alert": "TestPushtoAPID"}, "apids": ["****4"]}' https://go.urbanairship.com/api/push/
```

I am getting the following response :

```
{
    "push_id": "33e95250-f2b9-11e2-a8d0-14feb5d31f47"
}
```

In spite of this, I am not able to see any notification on my device.

```
Part of Android Manifest 
<!-- REQUIRED for Urban Airship GCM--> 
<receiver android:name="com.urbanairship.CoreReceiver" /> 
<receiver android:name="com.urbanairship.push.GCMPushReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND"> 
    <intent-filter> 
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" /> 
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Part of MainActivity:

```
UAirship.takeOff(this.getApplication(), options); 
PushManager.enablePush(); 
PushManager.shared().setIntentReceiver(IntentReceiver.class); 
String apid = PushManager.shared().getAPID();
```

Comment: What have you tried? What have you uncovered? The null pointer exception is because you are using a variable that is not instantiated somewhere within `Unable to start receiver com.urbanairship.push.GCMPushReceiver: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-22 16:27:06.385: E/AndroidRuntime(6071): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2277)` Have you your broadcast receiver declared in your manifest or have you instantiated it?

Comment: Please show the code for that to confirm.

Comment: OP: Please stop posting code in the comments, re-edit your question as those comments make the code unreadable.

Comment: Is that actually in your manifest? You're missing closing tags...

Comment: OP: I have edited and reformatted your code, please delete those comments that has the code to clean this up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to have been because the particular apid got attached to a different UA app that I used for debugging. I created a new app and assumed that the same apid can get attached to this app too. That is not the case. I tried using a new device and it is working fine.

Answer (score 3):

Actually the problem was in implementation of the library correctly.

The `takeOff` as well as the other configuration code should be in the `OnCreate` of the [`Application`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) class which is used for [maintaining *global state* of the application](http://www.intertech.com/Blog/androids-application-class/).This is where most of us go wrong.We put it in the foreground `Activity`s `OnCreate`.

Next you need to mention the *fully qualified name* of the `Application` class which you are using in the `AndroidManifest.xml` within your application tag this way:

```
 <application
        android:name="com.popa.app.MyApplication"
        ..
```

**This** is how it is to be implemented as mentioned in the [**original docs of UA**](http://docs.urbanairship.com/build/push/android.html#enabling-push-notifications).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same NPE as you but had a different reason/solution. In my case I had the proper UA services/receivers in my AndroidManifest.xml, but forgot to call UAirship.takeOff(). After I included the following code, the NPE went away:

```
    UAirship.takeOff(application, AirshipConfigOptions.loadDefaultOptions(application));
    PushManager.enablePush();
```

Comment: I found another (similar) cause to the above NPE. In order to improve performance, I delayed the call to takeOff() until 30 seconds after my app started and I'm seeing the NPE again. It seems to me that the UrbanAirship code registers its GCMPushReceiver even if takeOff() is not invoked. That GCMPushReceiver then reacts to GCM broadcasts and throws an NPE if takeOff() has not been invoked yet. This was probably either a mistake the UA folks made when coding their UA Android library or a compromise they made due to the way GCM works.

Answer (score 0):

From the OP's comments, and reading the [documentation](http://docs.urbanairship.com/android-lib/reference/com/urbanairship/push/PushManager.html#setIntentReceiver%28java.lang.Class%3C?%20extends%20android.content.BroadcastReceiver%3E%29) source, it appears it is incorrectly instantiated.

If `IntentReceiver` is a subclass of `BroadcastReceiver`, as per in the documentation, then the following should do it:

```
class IntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent argIntent) {
        // Handle it here
    }
}
```

The actual instantiation for it would be in this form:

```
IntentReceiver intentRcvr = new BroadcastReceiver();
PushManager.enablePush();
PushManager.shared().setIntentReceiver(intentRcvr); // TAKE NOTE!
// Rest of code.
```

Answer (score 0):

This makes me suspect that you haven't set up your AndroidManifest.xml correctly:

`07-22 16:27:06.385: E/AndroidRuntime(6071): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-22 16:27:06.385: E/AndroidRuntime(6071): at com.urbanairship.UAirship.getPackageName(Unknown Source)`

Have you added the fully qualified package name of your IntentReceiver to the AndroidManifest.xml? If I comment mine out, I get your exact error.

```
<!-- OPTIONAL, if you want to receive push, push opened and registration completed intents -->
<receiver android:name="com.XXXX.IntentReceiver" />
```

@t0mm13b Unfortunately I can't get your code to compile - you can't instantiate `BroadcastReceiver`, and [PushManager.shared().setIntentReceiver()](http://docs.urbanairship.com/android-lib/reference/com/urbanairship/push/PushManager.html#setIntentReceiver%28java.lang.Class%3C?%20extends%20android.content.BroadcastReceiver%3E%29) doesn't accept instantiated objects, only `Class<? extends BroadcastReceiver>` - therefore `IntentReceiver.class` is actually the correct parameter to pass through.